# How to set up chat rooms with limited access in Django? That is, we allow connections only from users registered in a particular chat room?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I recently joined a friend and his colleague in creating a social network-like website. I have sizeable programming experience, though no experience with Django. The friends have intermediate experience in general, but distinctly more with Django than me.

We want to implement chat rooms, which behave similar to e.g. WhatsApp groups: Upon certain events, the server can add users to a particular chatroom and conversely also remove them. The users can send and recieve messages to and from that chatroom when connected and retrieve old messages which they missed since the last time they were online.

My question is no to ask for the standard way to implement that system. We already have chat rooms where everyone can join via the right URL. However that is evidently not sufficient because we can't restrict access yet.

Up to this point, we are using Django channels and we have set up the public chat rooms in accordance with the [Channels Tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/).

I have already seen the [django private chat package](https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-private-chat/). However, I am reluctant to integrate that because I'm trying to avoid cluttering the project with packages and more importantly am trying to minimize the new technologies that we, particularily I, have to learn at the moment.

One idea that I had was storing all users that have access to a chat room in the room's model. When somebody subsequently tries to connect to the chat room, we dynamically only allow it if the user is registered within those stored users. However, I have performance, security and maintainability concerns with that approach that I currently cannot properly assess as a beginner. And that's the reasing why I'm asking for help here. More specifically, I'm asking if there are any established best practices, which, I assume, there are plenty due to the mundane and simple nature of the endeavour.

I'm grateful for any help or suggestions. Have a great day!
Greetings, Marc :D

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your idea of having a DB model to track the Rooms and then a many to many relationship from that to the users is the best way to do this.

Then in the consumer you can check if the user connecting has access. This check should only need to happen in the connect method of the consumer so should not be to much of a perfomance impact.

From a security perspective the main thing you need to deal with is user authentication, this will depend a lot on how you are planning on using the websocket, if it is just used through a webpage were the user is already logged into the same domain or if it is going to be used cross domain or from a client (mobile/desktop) application.